# How to calculate simple trigonometric problem

Tags: trigonometry

I tried for an hour or so to solve this but I can't show the way to the solution. How does one solve the below problem?

$\tan(\sin^{-1}(1/3))$?

Is the solution periodic because it is a tangent?

Comment: Solve for what? To solve something you need at least an equation. You have only an expression. Do you search the roots, but if yes, where is your variable?

Comment: @halirutan This is a standard mathematics problem in trigonometry.  By "solve", the OP means evaluate.  He needs to set up a right triangle and work it out.  It is not a question about the software *Mathematica*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to derive compositions of trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426399/how-to-derive-compositions-of-trigonometric-and-inverse-trigonometric-functions)

Answer (score 2):

Please look in the first row of the Wikipedia table on [Relationships between trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_function#Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions). There you find the relation that

$$\tan(\arcsin(x))=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

This gives you immediately the correct result of

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Now, your task is to understand where this relation comes from.

As MichaelE2 pointed out, an alternative would be to [ask WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(sin%5E-1(1%2F3))

> [image]

Comment: Or simply http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(sin%5E-1(1%2F3))

Answer (score 1):

To solve a problem like $\tan(\sin^{-1}(a/b))$, one can first set up a right triangle for $\sin^{-1}(a/b)$ by letting the hypotenuse be $b$ and the altitude be $a$. (If $a/b$ is negative, put the negative sign with $a$.) Then solve for the base, $\sqrt{b^2-a^2}$. The tangent is the altitude divided by the base, or $a / \sqrt{b^2-a^2}$.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nicely done, Michael! +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would do it if you didn't have Wikipedia.

$$\tan\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)
=\frac{\sin\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)}{\cos\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)}
=\frac{\sin\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)}}
=\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$$