# Proving that a $f:\mathbb{R} \to (-1,1); x \mapsto \frac {x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ is bijective

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to prove that a function is bijective and I really am not sure how to go about it. I know that I must show that the function is both injective and surjective for it to be bijective. The function that I am trying to prove is bijective is:

$f:\mathbb{R} \to (-1,1); x \mapsto \frac {x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

So to prove that it is injective, would I begin by letting $x, y \in (-1,1)$ and have:

$\frac {x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \frac {y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$

Would this be the right way of going about it? I am not sure on how to prove that it is surjective.

Comment: I'd square both sides and then multiply both sides by $(1+x^2)(1+y^2)$.

Comment: You've got a fine start: can you make the case that your equation holds if and only if $x = y$? If so, then the function is injective. See @GitGud's suggestion above. But note, we need for $x, y \in \mathbb R$, and $f(x), f(y) \in (-1, 1)$.

Comment: Ok so I have $x^2(1+y^2)=y^2(1+x^2)$ so I presume this equation holds iff $x=y$? So this would prove that the function is injective?

Comment: @Aaron Well the *immediate* consequence is merely $x^2=y^2$, so $x=\pm y$, but ...

Comment: As Git Gud mentioned in another question, doesn't the starting assumption imply that the signs are the same?

Comment: @Aaron That's correct. But do you understand why?

Comment: Not sure... would it simply be due to the fact that $\frac {x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ can be negative or positive?

Comment: Suppose $x$ and $y$ have different signs (for instance $x>0$ and $y<0$), if $\frac {x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \frac {y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$, then the LHS is positive because $x$ is positive and $\sqrt \cdot$ is positive, however, the RHS is negative over positive, which yields negative. So you get that a positive numbers equals a negative number, which is a contradiction. Therefore $x$ and $y$ can't have different signs.

Comment: Yep :) now for surjectivity, would I follow what N.S. said in regards to setting $y=\frac {x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Comment: Yes, solve for $y$.You'll need to use the quadratic formula to get $y$ as a function of $x$. For each $y$you'll get two $x$'s, but only one works. To find out which, follow his hint: 'don't forget that $y$ must have the same sign as $x$'.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\frac {x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \frac {y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} \Rightarrow x\sqrt{1+y^2}=y\sqrt{1+x^2}$$
and square both side.

For onto, let $y \in (-1,1)$ try to solve

$$\frac {x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = y \,.$$

This is the same as

$$x=y\sqrt{1+y^2}$$

square again both sides, and don't forget that $y$ must have the same sign as $x$...

P.S. Don't forget to start the problem by showing that $f$ is well defines, that is $f(x) \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: Squaring yields $x^2=y^2$, so further investigation is necessary.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe That's why i said hint... $x^2=y^2$ is easy to solve, and also easy to check which of the two solutions is wrong/right....

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I know you know this, but I'll reply to help the OP. The starting assumption is that $\frac {x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \frac {y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$, among other things, this implies that $x$ and $y$ have the same sign.

Comment: @GitGud I don't doubt -- even in my weirdest dreams -- that you're aware of that extra consideration: but how high do you estimate the beginner's percentage  which are aware of that, too?  My estimate would be less than a third.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe The fact that I thought that the OP could have some trouble with it is the reason why I explained how to find $x=y$. Meaning I agree with you in principle, but I won't commit to a number $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- for injectivity: Try to find a left inverse
- for surjectivity: prove that $f$ is increasing and have a look at $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)$

Comment: Though useful, I think this is too conceptual to the apparent level of the OP. (+1 because of future readers).

Comment: @GitGud You are completely right. I was unsure to post it. But as usual, "the more the better" :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Show that $f = \sin \circ \arctan$. What can you say about those two functions?

Comment: You should type that answer in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$. [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426399/how-to-derive-compositions-of-trigonometric-and-inverse-trigonometric-functions).

Comment: @GitGud, I don't understand what you mean. Should I have linked to a derivation? This fact is easy to verify, so I didn't think it necessary.

Comment: I meant your answer is out of the blue $\ddot \smile$.