# Use the identity $\cos^2x+ \sin^2x=1$ to show that $\cos(\arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Use the identity $\cos^2x+ \sin^2x=1$ to show that $\cos(\arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

How do I begin? I have no idea where to start...

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426399/how-to-derive-compositions-of-trigonometric-and-inverse-trigonometric-functions/426414#426414).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let  $\displaystyle\arcsin x=\theta\implies\sin\theta= x$

and $\displaystyle-\frac\pi2\le \theta\le \frac\pi2$  ([Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) value)

$\displaystyle\cos(\arcsin x)=\cos\theta=+\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: put $\arcsin(x)=y$, so $\sin(y)=x$. Now use the formula to express $\cos(y)$ in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$. Subtract $\sin^2x$ from both sides to get $$\cos^2 x = 1 - \sin^2 x.$$ Take the square root to get $$\cos x = \pm \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}.$$ Now let $x = \arcsin y$, and you have your formula :) (since $\sin^2(\arcsin y))=y^2$).