# $\tan \left(\sec ^{-1}(x)\right)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$\tan \left(\sec ^{-1}(x)\right)$$

I know that sec(?)=$\frac{x}{1}$ and that sec=hyp/adj, therefore I conclude that hyp=x and adj=1 and that op=$\sqrt{x^2-1}$

Since Tan = opp/adj I thought the answer was the same as op. However I do not understand how this is done? cause my conclusion is wrong! The answer provided is this:

[image]

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426399/how-to-derive-compositions-of-trigonometric-and-inverse-trigonometric-functions/426414#426414).

Comment: What is your conclusion?

Comment: My conclusion is sqrt(x^2-1) however the answer is suppose to be sqrt(x^2-1)*sgn(x)

Comment: Your conclusion is right when $x>0$.  Only when $x<0$ is it incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

In this triangle, we have:

$$\sec(\theta)=\frac{\text{hypotenuse}}{\text{adjacent}} \Rightarrow \theta=\sec^{-1}\Big(\frac{\text{hypotenuse}}{\text{adjacent}}\Big)$$

In your problem, $\theta=\sec^{-1}(x)$, so $\text{hypotenuse}=x$, $\text{adjacent}=1$ and $\text{opposite}=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ (Pythagorean Theorem).

Hence, $$\tan(\sec^{-1}x)=\tan(\theta)=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{1}=\boxed{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

Comment: sqrt(x^2-1)*sgn(x) is suppose to be the answer

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Could you have a look at the updated question? I do not see what they have done

Comment: What is the name and the author of the book you're using?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$
\tan^2 u + 1 = \sec^2 u
$$
and 
$$
\tan u = \pm\sqrt{\sec^2 u -1}
$$
Can you see what happens when you place $u = \sec^{-1}x$?