# When simplifying $\sin(\arctan(x))$, why is negative $x$ not considered?

Tags: trigonometry

Let $u = \arctan(x)$, hence $x = \tan(u)$ for $u$ belongs in $(-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2)$. Since $u$ belongs in $(-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2)$, we consider $\sin(u)$ where $u$ belongs in $(-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2)$.

I used the unit circle to determine that the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ and got an answer $\sin(u) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$ when I consider than the angle $u$ lies between $(0, \frac\pi2)$.

That's what my textbook says too. However, why don't we also consider when $x$ is negative, and the angle $u$ lies between $(-\frac\pi2, 0)$ ?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426399/how-to-derive-compositions-of-trigonometric-and-inverse-trigonometric-functions/426414#426414).

Comment: i think it is right , even for (-π/2,0)

Comment: When $x<0$ and $u\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},0\right)$, sine is also negative. But in that case, we also have $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}<0$. So thankfully/coincidentally, $\sin (\arctan x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ is always true. The same thing happens for $\cos (\arctan x)$, where again thankfully/coincidentally the signs work out right and we always have  $\cos (\arctan x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. Contrast this to the half-angle formulae where we have to worry about the signs.

Answer (score 8):

An angle $\theta$ is said to be in *standard position* if its vertex is at the origin and its initial side lies on the positive $x$-axis.

The *unit circle* is the circle with radius $1$ and center at the origin of the coordinate plane.

We define the *cosine* and *sine* of an angle in standard position to be, respectively, the $x$-coordinate and $y$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle.  We define the *tangent* of an angle in standard position to be the $y$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of the angle intersects the line $x = 1$.  See the diagram below.

[image: trigonometric function definitions]

If $\theta = \arctan x$, then $\tan\theta = x$ and $-\dfrac{\pi}{2} < x < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.  Consequently, we can draw a right triangle in the first quadrant or fourth quadrant, as shown below.

[image: sine of arctangent of x diagrams]

If $x > 0$, we draw a right triangle in the first quadrant with opposite side of length $|x| = x$, adjacent side of length $1$, and hypotenuse of length $\sqrt{1 + x^2}$.

If $x < 0$, we draw a right triangle in the fourth quadrant with opposite side of length $|x| = -x$, adjacent side of length $1$, and hypotenuse of length $\sqrt{1 + x^2}$.

If $x = 0$, we draw the line segment from $0$ to $1$ on the positive $x$-axis.  The opposite side has length $|x| = |0| = 0$, the adjacent side has length $1$, and the hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{1 + x^2} = \sqrt{1 + 0^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1$.

In each case, the terminal side of the angle intersects the line $x = 1$ at the point $(1, x)$ (yes, I am using $x$ in two different ways here), so the tangent of the angle is $x$.

We find the sine of the arctangent of $x$ by dividing the $y$-coordinate of the point $(1, x)$ by its distance from the origin.  Hence, in each case,

$$\sin[\arctan(x)] = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}$$

Note that since the denominator is always positive, the sign of $\sin[\arctan(x)]$ is equal to the sign of $x$.

Since the numerator of $\sin[\arctan(x)]$ is the $y$-coordinate of the point $(1, x)$ rather than the length of the side opposite angle $\theta$, we obtain the same result when we draw the triangle in the fourth quadrant as we do if we draw it in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 6):

Draw the right angle triangle.

Opposite side = x, adjacent side = 1, hypotenuse= $\sqrt{1+x^2}$, so

$$ \sin(...) = \pm \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} $$

two signs due to $\sqrt .. $

EDIT1

Why the double sign? $\pm $ It is easy to see. Arctan has two signs. It can be $x$ or $x + \pi $
x>0
Sine of this argunent is positive if in the first quadrant and negative if in the the third.
x< 0
Sine of this argunent is negative if in the first quadrant and positive if in the the third.
While we are simplifying we have **in no way neglected** the negative sign.

Comment: This is wrong. N. F. Taussig's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If $-\frac\pi2\lt u\lt\frac\pi2$, then $\cos(u)\gt0$. Therefore, if $\tan(u)=x$, then $\cos(u)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Thus, if $\arctan(x)=u$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(u)
&=\tan(u)\cos(u)\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, since $\sin(x)$ and $\arctan(x)$ are odd functions,
$$
\sin(\arctan(-x))=-\sin(\arctan(x))
$$

Comment: See the deleted comment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using $x$ in $u = \arctan x$ and then referring to the $xy$-plane causes $x$ to have two different meanings.

Try $\theta = \arctan t$

You can draw a picture of $\theta = \arctan t$ by considering the triangle below with vertices at $(0,0), (1,0), \text{and} \ (1,t)$. The unit circle is unnecessary.
Note that the picture implies $\sin \theta = \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$, and the sign is handled correctly by the sign of $t$. If your book says otherwise, then it is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add some additional information regarding user46234's comment, we can also understand the omission of a $\pm$ sign as a simple consequence of algebra.

Here are the relevant pieces of information to conclude this:

- By definition, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$
- $\arctan$ is a strictly increasing function bounded between $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$
- $\arctan(0)=0$
- $\sin(x) \geq 0$ if $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $\sin(x) \lt 0$ if $x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},0)$
- $\cos(x) \gt 0$ if $x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

---

Working forward from the above bulleted points:

Let $y=\arctan(x)$.We know that $y \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. By definition, $\tan(y)=\tan\circ \arctan(x)=x \implies \frac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)}=x$

To further simplify, we use the Pythagorean identity $\cos^2(y)+\sin^2(y)=1 \implies \cos^2(y)=1-\sin^2(y)$. Taking the square root of both sides yields: $|\cos(y)|=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(y)}$.  Note that $y \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, which means that $\cos(y) \gt 0$...and therefore $|\cos(y)|=\cos(y)$, so that we have $\cos(y)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(y)}$.

We then have that $x=\frac{\sin(y)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(y)}}$. Rearranging and then squaring gives us $\big(1-\sin^2(y)\big)\cdot x^2=\sin^2(y)$. Because $x=\tan(y)$, we can use the tangent expression of the Pythagorean identity to further simplify: $1+\frac{\sin^2(y)}{\cos^2(y)}=\frac{1}{\cos^2(y)} \implies1+\tan^2(y)=\frac{1}{1-\sin^2(y)} \implies \frac{1}{1+\tan^2(y)}=1-\sin^2(y) \implies\frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-\sin^2(y)$. Note that in order to apply this substitution, we need to make sure that $\cos(y) \neq 0$...however, given that $y \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, we know that $\cos(y) \neq 0$. We can then apply the relevant substitution that gives us:

$$\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=\sin^2(y)$$

Taking the square root of this expression gives us:

$$\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=|\sin(y)| \quad (\dagger_1)$$

Now, suppose $x \geq 0$. Then $y \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. We then know that $\sin(y) \geq 0$, so we must have that $|x|=x$ and $|\sin(y)|=\sin(y)$. Under these circumstances, $(\dagger_1)$ is just $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\sin(y)$.

Next, suppose $x \lt 0$. Then $y \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},0)$. We then know that $\sin(y) \lt 0$, so we must have that $|x|=-x$ and $|\sin(y)|=-\sin(y)$. Under these circumstances, $(\dagger_1)$ is $\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=-\sin(y)$, which can of course be rewritten as $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\sin(y)$.

Thus, across all relevant cases, we must have that $\sin(\arctan(x))=\sin(y)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$