# Derivative of $\arctan(x)$

Tags: derivatives, inverse

I am meant to find the derivative of $\arctan(x)$ from the definition of derivative of an inverse function $(1/(f '(f^{-1}(x)))$.

Well, I have found this question asked and explained, however all the explanations said that $(\tan(x))' = \sec^2(x)$.

I have never met with the $\sec$ function, so i have been trying to make it work with the formula $(\tan(x))' = 1/(\cos^2(x))$ instead. Thus writing this down:

$$\begin{align}
((f^{-1})(x)) &= \arctan (x)\\[1ex]
(f(x)) &= \tan (x)\\[1ex]
(f '(x)) &= \frac1{\cos^2 x}
\end{align}$$

So from the inverse derivative formula the equation should look something like this:

$$(\arctan(x))' = \frac1{\frac1{\cos^2(\arctan x)}}$$

I rewrote the right side to

$$\frac{\sin^2(\arctan x)}{\tan^2(\arctan x)}$$

which equals

$$\frac{\sin^2(\arctan x)}{x^2}$$

And that is pretty much the furthest I can get, so if you could show me where I've done a mistake or how to go on with my solution, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970505/simplify-sin-arctanx

Comment: Derivative, not derivation.

Comment: And the verb is to differentiate, not to derive

Comment: Thanks for teaching me the right terms, i dont study in english, so i tried to translate from my native language :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=\tan x\iff x=\arctan y\implies (\arctan y)'=\frac1{\tan'\left(\arctan y\right)'}=\frac1{\frac1{\cos^2\arctan y}}=$$

$$=\cos^2\arctan y=\frac1{1+\tan^2\arctan y}=\frac1{1+y^2}$$

We used above the identity

$$1+\tan^2\alpha=\frac1{\cos^2\alpha}\iff \cos^2\alpha=\frac1{1+\tan^2\alpha}$$

Comment: Thanks alot, i did not know about the $(cos^2(x)) = 1/(1+tan^2(x))$ identity, turns out to be the deal breaker here.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method you followed, you actually almost had found the answer.
But you needed to be able to simplify the expression
$\sin^2(\arctan(x)).$

Recall that $\arctan(x)$ is an angle $\theta$ such that
$\tan(\theta) = x.$

Therefore $\sin^2(\arctan(x)) = \sin^2(\theta)$ where $\tan(\theta) = x.$

But if $\tan(\theta) = x,$ what is $\sin^2(\theta)$?
This is something you can approach with algebra and trigonometric
identities, but as a device to help me recall what the answer should be
I find it useful sometimes to just construct a suitable right triangle.
In this case the triangle has legs $1$ and $x$ so that the angle
opposite leg $x$ is $\theta = \arctan(x).$

The hypotenuse of the triangle is $\sqrt{1+x^2},$ so looking at the angle
opposite leg $x$, its sine (opposite/hypotenuse) is
$$
\sin(\arctan(x)) = \sin(\theta) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$
When we square this and divide by $x^2$ we have
$$
\frac{\sin^2(\arctan(x))}{x^2}
 = \frac{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)^2}{x^2}
 = \frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$