# How to prove this following trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry

How can I prove the equation below?
$$\sin(\arccos(x))=\cos(\arcsin(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$$
$$-1\leq{x}\leq1$$

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to derive compositions of trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426399/how-to-derive-compositions-of-trigonometric-and-inverse-trigonometric-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the Pythagorean identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, that for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$,
$$\cos x = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}.$$

Therefore
$$\cos(\arcsin x) = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2(\arcsin x)} = \sqrt{1 - x^2},$$
because $\sin(\arcsin x) = x$ for every $x \in [-1, 1]$.

The other one is very similar, can you finish the exercise?

Comment: Thanks @AlirezaGhaffari for noticing the typos. I corrected them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following fact:

$$\sin^2 (x) + \cos^2 (x) = 1$$

Let's define $y=\arccos x$. Thus we have:

$$\sin^2 y + \cos^2 y = 1 \implies \\ \sin^2 y + x^2 = 1   \implies \\\sin^2 y = 1-x^2 \implies \\ \sin y = \sqrt{(1-x^2) } \implies \\\sin(\arccos x) = \sqrt{(1-x^2)}$$

Notice that $\cos(\arccos x ) = x$ for every $x \in [-1, 1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the definition: Ratio of sides of a right angled triangle.

[image: Trig Triangle]

Answer (score 0):

Start from the identity $\sin^2 y+\cos^2 y=1$ where $y=\arccos x$ this leads $\sin^2\arccos x+x^2=1$ (because $\cos \arccos x=x$) and thus the identity for sine. Same with cosine