# Prove that $\sin(2\sin^{-1}(\alpha)) = 2\alpha \sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}$.

Tags: calculus

> Prove that $\sin(2\sin^{-1}(\alpha)) = 2\alpha \sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}$.

I was doing a trigonometric substitution problem in Calculus and came across this and wanted to know the proof of it.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426399/how-to-derive-compositions-of-trigonometric-and-inverse-trigonometric-functions) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\alpha = \sin \phi$, then
$$ 2\alpha\sqrt{1-\alpha^2} = 2\sin\phi|\cos\phi| = \sin2\phi \text{ or } -\sin2\phi
$$

Comment: It should be $2\sin \phi|\cos \phi|$. Though you can let $\phi\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: @user236182 Thanks. It is fixed.

Comment: There exists a $\phi\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ such that $\alpha =\sin \phi$. Then you'll get $\sin 2\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the double angle formula, $\sin{2 p} = 2 \sin{p} \cos{p}$ and then use the fact that $\sin^2 p + \cos^2 p = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Double angular formel: $sin(2p)=2*cos(p)*sin(p)=2*\sqrt{1-sin^2(p)}*sin(p)$
Let $\;p=sin^{-1}(\alpha)\quad$ and you get your result

Comment: It's only true if $p\in[-\pi/2+2\pi k,\pi/2+2\pi k],\, k\in\mathbb Z$. $\, \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}=|\cos x|$.