# Using the chain rule to guess the derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I learned that you can use the product rule to guess what the derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ should be, you just use the fact that $(\frac{1}{x}\cdot x) = 1$ and differentiate both sides and solve for $(\frac{1}{x})'$.
My teacher said that there is a similar trick for guessing the derivative of $(\frac{1}{x})$ using the chain rule, I tried using the fact that $\frac{1}{x}\circ\frac{1}{x}= x$ but I am stuck.

Comment: You won’t be able to get it from the fact that $f\circ f= \mathrm{id}$ (what you are trying to do), because $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is not the only function with this property: if you have $g(x) = -x$, then you also have that $g\circ g = \mathrm{id}$, but of course $f’(x)\neq g’(x)$. In short, you are barking up the wrong tree trying to use that property.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think that claim is premature just from your comments. It's the wrong tree if one is going for $f\circ f$, but there could be some other useful compositions.

Comment: @GitGud: I very carefully did not say anything about using the chain rule in general. I very specifically and explicitly talked about the specific attempt at using the fact that $f\circ f = \mathrm{id}$, which is in fact what the OP is talking about. So, since my comment is only about “going for $f\circ f$,” **explicitly** (which I specify *twice*), I have to say your comment is addressing a strawman in which I have no part.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I was about to add an adendum to my comment saying that my comment assumed that "property" meant the composition. I stand corrected.

Comment: Using $x=1/(\frac1x)=u(v(x))$ just leads to $\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{dv}{dx}$, which is obviously true since $u(x) =x. $ So this is the wrong composition to try.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=\frac1x$$
$$\log \circ \,\,f=-\log x$$
$$(\log \circ \,\,f)’=(-\log x)’$$
$$f’\frac 1f=-\frac1x$$
$$f’=-\frac fx=-\frac 1{x^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

This works, but I'm not sure if it is allowed. Depends on whether you know the derivative of $\log$.

For any positive real number $x$, set $f(x)=\dfrac 1 x, g(x)=\log(x)$ and $h(x)=-\log(x)$. Note that $g\circ f=h$ and

$$
\begin{align}
(g\circ f)(x) = h(x) &\implies g'(f(x))f'(x)=h'(x)\\
&\implies f'(x) = h'(x)/g'(f(x))\\
&\implies f'(x)=-\log'(x)/\log'\left(1/x\right)\\
&\implies f'(x) = -\dfrac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{1/x}}\\
&\implies f'(x) = -\dfrac{1}{x^2}
\end{align}
$$

The crucial point here is that $g'=f^{-1}$. Not unlike what I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426399/how-to-derive-compositions-of-trigonometric-and-inverse-trigonometric-functions/426414#426414).

Comment: At least you've answered the actual question!